# Embedding Log4j and AOP For Exception Logging In Java Swing Application

Tags: java, swing, exception, log4j, aop

I am developing An ERP for industry using Java Swing in NetBeans. I want to log the exceptions raised using [log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)! and  [AOP](http://blog.octo.com/en/aop-and-swing-a-smart-association/). I did lot of searching but did not get the integration of AOP with Swing based appplications as most examples are for web frame works (e.g Spring). Lots of Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You want to inject your loggers?

Comment: as @kriegaex already mentioned: your question is too broad (voting to close). Please break it down into a concrete coding problem.

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Comment: Please also give me up vote as I also accepted your answer and gave up vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fail to see your problem. Swing or not, you are just using Java classes. If you can apply [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) to other Java classes, you can also apply it to Swing classes. Just give it a try, AOP with AspectJ is real fun once you understand the basic concepts. If you have a concrete question, I will be happy to help if I can.

---

**Update:** Okay, I just had some slack time and used some [sample code](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=231) to hack a quick demo for you.

Minimal Swing example throwing two RuntimeExceptions, one during creation of the main window and another one when you click "OK" in the pop-up dialog:

```java
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public final class MinimalSwingApplication {
    public static void main(String... aArgs) {
        MinimalSwingApplication app = new MinimalSwingApplication();
        app.buildAndDisplayGui();
    }

    private void buildAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main window");
        buildContent(frame);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void buildContent(JFrame aFrame) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
        JButton ok = new JButton("Show pop-up dialog");
        ok.addActionListener(new ShowDialog(aFrame));
        panel.add(ok);
        aFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        throw new RuntimeException("Oops!");
    }

    private static final class ShowDialog implements ActionListener {
        private JFrame fFrame;

        ShowDialog(JFrame aFrame) {
            fFrame = aFrame;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aEvent) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(fFrame, "I am the a pop-up dialog");
            throw new RuntimeException("Something unexpected happened here");
        }
    }
}
```

A sample aspect which logs exceptions (using JDK logging, but you can easily switch to Log4J):

```java
import java.util.logging.*;

public aspect SwingExceptionLogger {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SwingExceptionLogger.class.getName());

    Object around() : execution(* MinimalSwingApplication..*(..)) {
        try {
            return proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Swing exception: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output for starting the application and opening/closing the pop-up dialog twice:

```
10.11.2012 09:42:28 MinimalSwingApplication buildContent_aroundBody5$advice
WARNUNG: Swing exception: Oops!
10.11.2012 09:42:33 MinimalSwingApplication$ShowDialog actionPerformed_aroundBody1$advice
WARNUNG: Swing exception: Something unexpected happened here
10.11.2012 09:42:37 MinimalSwingApplication$ShowDialog actionPerformed_aroundBody1$advice
WARNUNG: Swing exception: Something unexpected happened here
```

You can always refine the pointcut to only log stuff from the AWT/Swing threads if that is what you want. You could also rethrow the exception instead of swallowing it. Feel free to experiment or ask.

Comment: please give me some example for using AOP pointcuts and features with swing based applications

Comment: please give me some example for using AOP pointcuts and other features with swing based applications @kriegaex

Comment: Give me a concrete problem and some sample code to work with, please. I guess noone here wants to create a full example or tutotial for you just like that. Have you ever used AspectJ and experienced a specific problem working with it? Narrow down the scope, please.

Comment: Check the update. I added sample code because you seem to be too lazy to provide any by yourself.